# The procedure to matching words from a list to words in a line

Tags: python, string, list, integer, tweets

The following are two examples of many lines that I need to analyze and extract specific words from.

```
[40.748330000000003, -73.878609999999995] 6 2011-08-28 19:52:47 Sometimes I wish my life was a movie; #unreal I hate the fact I feel lonely surrounded by so many ppl


[37.786221300000001, -122.1965002] 6 2011-08-28 19:55:26 I wish I could lay up with the love of my life And watch cartoons all day.
```

**The coordinates and numbers are ignored**

The case is to find how many of the words in each tweet line are present in this keywords list:

```
['hate', 1]
['hurt', 1]
['hurting', 1]
['like', 5]
['lonely', 1]
['love', 10]
```

And also, find the sum of the values (e.g ['love', **10**]) of the keywords found in each tweet line.

For example, for the sentence

```
'I hate to feel lonely at times'
```

The sum of sentiments values for **hate=1** and **lonely=1** is equal to 2.
And the no. of words in the line is 7.

I've tried to use list into lists method and even trying to go through each sentence and keywords, but those haven't worked because the no. of tweets and keywords are several and I need to use loop format to find the values.

**What I want to find out is the sum of sentiment values of the keywords found in each line and how many words there were in each line**

Appreciate your insight in advance!! :)

My Code:

```
try:
    KeywordFileName=input('Input keyword file name: ')
    KeywordFile = open(KeywordFileName, 'r')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('The file you entered does not exist or is not in the directory')
    exit()
KeyLine = KeywordFile.readline()
while KeyLine != '':
    if list != []:
        KeyLine = KeywordFile.readline()
        KeyLine = KeyLine.rstrip()
        list = KeyLine.split(',')
        list[1] = int(list[1])
        print(list)
    else:
        break

try:
    TweetFileName = input('Input Tweet file name: ')
    TweetFile = open(TweetFileName, 'r')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('The file you entered does not exist or is not in the directory')
    exit()

TweetLine = TweetFile.readline()
while TweetLine != '':
    TweetLine = TweetFile.readline()
    TweetLine = TweetLine.rstrip()
```

Comment: You would be better of removing the numbers and using ntlk word tokenize and doing a count.

Comment: I think you might want to start by casting the whole line as a string and then use Regex to keep only the bit to the right of the timestamp.  Secondly, I would save your keywords list as a dictionary. It's hard to help you directly because your code is incomplete and doesn't include all the things that are requirements for your project.

Comment: @jake , those lines are in a  .txt file or what ?

Answer (score 1):

If your tweets are in a .txt [like this file](https://pastebin.com/E6MLVaW5) and pattern of lines of tweets are same as you described in the question then you can try this approach:

```
import re
import json
pattern=r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s([a-zA-Z].+)'
sentiment_dict={'hate' :1,'hurt':1,'hurting':1,'like':5,'lonely':1,'love':10}

final=[]
with open('senti.txt','r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = []

        match=re.finditer(pattern,line)
        for find in match:
            if find.group(1).split():
                final.append(find.group(1).split())

line=[]

for item in final:
    final_dict = {}

    for sub_item in item:
        if sub_item in sentiment_dict:
            if sub_item not in final_dict:
                final_dict[sub_item]=[sentiment_dict.get(sub_item)]
            else:
                final_dict[sub_item].append(sentiment_dict.get(sub_item))

    line.append((item,len(item),{key: sum(value) for key,value in final_dict.items()}))

result=json.dumps(line,indent=2)

print(result)
```

output:

```
[
  [
    [
      "Sometimes",       #tweets line or all words
      "I",
      "wish",
      "my",
      "life",
      "was",
      "a",
      "movie;",
      "#unreal",
      "I",
      "hate",
      "the",
      "fact",
      "I",
      "feel",
      "lonely",
      "surrounded",
      "by",
      "so",
      "many",
      "ppl"
    ],
    21,                   #count of words in tweets
    {
      "lonely": 1,        #sentiment count
      "hate": 1
    }
  ],
  [
    [
      "I",
      "wish",
      "I",
      "could",
      "lay",
      "up",
      "with",
      "the",
      "love",
      "of",
      "my",
      "life",
      "And",
      "watch",
      "cartoons",
      "all",
      "day."
    ],
    17,
    {
      "love": 10
    }
  ],
  [
    [
      "I",
      "hate",
      "to",
      "feel",
      "lonely",
      "at",
      "times"
    ],
    7,
    {
      "lonely": 1,
      "hate": 1
    }
  ]
]
```

> Options for regex if one pattern doesn't work for your file:

- `r'[a-zA-Z].+'   #if you use this change find.group(1) to find.group()`
- `r'(?<=\d.\s)[a-zA-Z].+'   #if you use this change find.group(1) to find.group()`
- `r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s([a-zA-Z].+)'`
- `r'\b\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (.+)'  #group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use word_tokenize from nltk library on a per tweet basis.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import collections
import re

# Sample text from above
s = '[40.748330000000003, -73.878609999999995] 6 2011-08-28 19:52:47 Sometimes I wish my life was a movie; #unreal I hate the fact I feel lonely surrounded by so many ppl'
num_regex = re.compile(r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?")
# Removing the numbers from the text
s = num_regex.sub('',s)
# Tokenization
tokens = word_tokenize(s)
# Counting the words
fdist = collections.Counter(tokens)
print fdist
```

`